# Application crash when I call a function

Tags: android, kotlin

Good evening / Hello everyone, I'm coming to you today with a small technical problem. I am currently developing a mobile application that requires reading a file and separating the information inside, the problem is that the application crashes when I call my function. I don't have error in logcat.

Here is the almost complete code so you can determine where the problem is coming from. The crashed function is "loadFile ()". (the package is intentionally missing)

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_schedule.*
import java.io.File

class ScheduleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var file: File? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule)
    val intent = intent
    val day = intent.getStringExtra("Day") // Return the selected day
    file = File(this.filesDir, day)
    loadFile()
    confirmButton.setOnClickListener {
        val a: String = course.text.toString()
        val b: String = course2.text.toString()
        val c: String = course3.text.toString()
        val d: String = course4.text.toString()
        val e: String = course5.text.toString()
        val f: String = course6.text.toString()
        val g: String = course7.text.toString()
        val h: String = course8.text.toString()
        val i: String = course9.text.toString()
        val j: String = ";"
        val fileText: String = a + j + b + j + c + j + d + j + e + j + f + j + g + j + h + j + i
        file!!.writeText(fileText)
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val backIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(backIntent)
    }
}

private fun loadFile() {
    if(file!!.readText().contains(";")) {
        val fileString: String = file!!.readText()
        var tempString: List<String> = fileString.split(";")
        course.setText(tempString[0])
        course2.setText(tempString[1])
        course3.setText(tempString[2])
        course4.setText(tempString[3])
        course5.setText(tempString[4])
        course6.setText(tempString[5])
        course7.setText(tempString[6])
        course8.setText(tempString[7])
        course9.setText(tempString[8])
    } else {
        //TODO(Handles error)
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show the stack trace. It will tell you which line of code is the problem.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't show any error.

Comment: There wouldn't be a stack trace in logcat without an error.

Comment: Here all I have : https://pastebin.com/WTV88suj

Comment: usually the stack trace is add as part of the question

Comment: @Antonio, I don't have a stacktrace. I doesn't have any error just the things on pastebin.

Comment: You can debug your app I Android studio and enable exception breakpoints, if that still doesn't give anything, put a breakpoint on every line and manually step through so you at least know at which line it's going wrong.

Comment: With the breakpoint, I can click on the Thursday button but I can't do anything else and logcat just repeat the same as the pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash occurs because your `File` does not exist.

Before you call `File.readText()` you need to check whether the `File` exists or not.

```kotlin
val myFile = requireNotNull(file)
if(myFile.exists() && myFile.readText().contains(";"))
```

Note:

1. You should check not only the logcat window but also your run and debug windows
2. You should consider doing file operations on a background thread

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val myFile = requireNotNull(file)
    if(myFile.exists() && myFile.readText().contains(";"))
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, you shouldn't do file operations on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks you, everything work. I'm new on the Android scene so.

Comment: Additionally, it's typically a bad idea to use the double-bang (or non-null asserted) operator (`!!`) as it may throw a `NullPointerException` if the value of `file` is `null`. Instead, use the safe-call operator (`?.`). See the [Kotlin documentation for more information on null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: Well, that depends on the use-case. You should not just use `?.` safe call operator everywhere. In cases where something can be null, you will either want to ignore the case when it is null (appropriate to use `?.`) or handle the null case and perform some other operation. In other cases, where you do not want something to be null its better to let the application crash so that you know something went wrong. Ofcourse, its better to use `requireNotNull(T?)` which throws an `IllegalArgumentException`